# usage of (object) in assigning values for hashmap

Tags: java

I saw a piece of java code using Hashmap as follows:

```
Map indata = new HashMap(12);
//load data
indata.put(“checking”, ((object) new  Double(1.0)));
indata.put(“PURPOSE”, ((object)"2”));
```

What confuse me is the two useages of "put" method, in which we have `((object) new  Double(1.0))`
  and `(object)"2"`. What do `(object)` function here? Any differences between `((object) new  Double(1.0))`
  and `(object)"2"`?

Comment: Both casts to object. While retrieval it makes difference, you need to re-cast first one as Double and second one as String.

Comment: There is no `object` in java.

Answer (score 2):

It's a cast to `Object` (note that it's capitalized in Java).

It seems to be pointless here, as the code will compile fine without the cast (since the non-generic version of `Map` expects `Object` as the type of both key and value, so passing a `String` or a `Double` does not require explicit casting).

Answer (score 1):

Q: What do (object) function here?
A:  Its just casting `String` and `Double`  to `Object.`

Q: Any differences between ((object) new Double(1.0)) and (object)"2"?
A: NO

```
((object) new Double(1.0))  - casting Double into Object
((object)"2”) -  casting String into Object
```

**EDIT:**
 Just realized from comments that it should be `Object` and not `object`

Comment: the question is "for what?" ;)

Comment: @dantuch: I have updated my answer to show what OP asked and what I understood (and answered). Please correct me if I am making any wrong assumptions.

Comment: Yes, you have answered it without mistake, but that's not the point. When you see **bad** code, don't try to tell or guess what it does, but instead just simply point what's wrong with it. Here casting to Object is just plain stupid :)

Comment: Anyway, +1 for your effort :)

Comment: @dantuch: Now onward will try not to miss a bad code before looking for whats wrong with it :)